# running rapidsai/rapidsai:cuda11.8-runtime-ubuntu22.04-py3.10 over straight "docker run" is not similar to using it over docker-compose.yml. Why?

Tags: docker-compose, gpu

host system: aws ec2 ubuntu 22.04 on g4dn(gpu instance)

docker version: Version:  24.0.5

Docker Compose version: v2.3.3

uname -r: 5.19.0-1029-aws

I ran docker pull and docker run for rapidsai/rapidsai:cuda11.8-runtime-ubuntu22.04-py3.10. When I exec into the container and check nvidia-smi, it works and shows GPU as Tesla T4.

Now,  I want to run it through docker-compose.yaml

my dockerfile

```
FROM rapidsai/rapidsai:cuda11.8-runtime-ubuntu22.04-py3.10
WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  libgl1-mesa-glx \
  ffmpeg \
  libsm6 \
  libxext6 \
  libtesseract-dev \
  tesseract-ocr \
  tesseract-ocr-nep \
  ghostscript \
  calibre \
  pandoc \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY /src/olen_iocr/models/OCR/nep.traineddata \
     /src/olen_iocr/models/OCR/eng.traineddata \
     /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata/

COPY . /app
COPY requirements.txt /app

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python3", "src/routes.py"]
```

My docker-compose.yaml file

```
version: "2.4"
services:
  olen-iocr:
  build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    container_name: olen-iocr
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    environment:
      - NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
    volumes:
      - ./src:/olen_iocr/src
      - ./tmp:/tmp
    working_dir: /olen_iocr/src
    command: python routes.py
    restart: always
```

When I launch docker compose up -d and exec into the container. I do not have nvidia-smi command. What am I missing?